# Dynamic BroadcastReceivers: LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver vs registerReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to receive broadcasts from a service with 2 different receivers. One receiver update's a view so I register it in the activity's onResume method.

When the app is not in the foreground I use the other receiver so I can show a system notification when the background service completes.

The code below is how I'm registering my receivers:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // unregister local
    unregisterReceiver(localReceiver);

    // register remote
    registerReceiver(remoteReceiver, filter);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // remove remote receiver
    // since remote is only registered in onPause it won't be registered during the first onResume call
    // so we want to ignore any exceptions
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(remoteReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No receiver registered, could be first time");
    }

    // add local receiver
    registerReceiver(localReceiver, filter);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "resumed. should be registered");
}
```

The two receiver's are instantiated like this at the top of the Activity class:

```
BroadcastReceiver localReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { ... };

WaitTimeReceiver remoteReceiver = new WaitTimeReceiver();
```

The Service makes the intent as:

```
broadcastIntent = new Intent(Support.SERVICE_BR);
broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

// later on sends using
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

The Filter in the Activity is made to match:

```
filter.addAction(Support.SERVICE_BR);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

Everything above is working the pause resume functionality works as expected, but my question is why the LocalBroadcastManager was not?

Using `LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)` and then calling `lbm.registerReceiver(localReceiver)` was not receiving any of my broadcasts for either.

Why wasn't the LocalBroadcastManager receiving any of my broadcasts?

Comment: Are you using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast()` to broadcast to the Receivers you've registered with `LocalBroadcastManager`? They're not going to catch regular broadcasts.

Comment: The answer to that is no. I'll update my question with that detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver`s registered with `LocalBroadcastManager` can only receive broadcasts sent with `LocalBroadcastManager`. Broadcasts sent with an `Activity`'s or `Service`'s `sendBroadcast()` method cannot be received by `LocalBroadcastManager` Receivers.

Use the `LocalBroadcastManager#sendBroadcast()` method instead. For example:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```