# Unable to update textview in Fragment from Service

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm running a service that runs audio. I've created a `TextView` in the layout of the fragment that should display the title of the track being played.

Currently I've set the `TextView` to be updated when the user selects a track from within the Fragment or clicks the skip to next or previous buttons:

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//other stuff

        String[] topText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topText_array);
        songNowPlayingLabel.setText("Now Playing : " + topText[position]);
   }


    button_skipNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    musicService.playNext();

                    songNowPlayingLabel.setText("Now Playing : " + topText[musicService.songPosn]);

                }
            });
```

However, the `TextView` does not update when the current track is completed and the Service automatically plays the next track. In addition, the application also makes use of a custom notification that is displayed when the app is no longer on screen but music is being played in the service. In this case when pressing the notification buttons for next/previous the `TextView` is not updated.

I want the `TextView` to be updated whenever the track is changed from the notification buttons as well or when the track is completed. For this I created a broadcast listener and added it to the `onStartCommand` of the `MusicService.java`. However this has no effect on the `TextView`.

I've gone through some other threads on the same issue but have been unable to resolve this problem. What am I doing wrong?

xml of the TextView

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songNowPlayingLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Relevant parts of MusicService.java

```
        static final public String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.myapplication.broadcastSongNowPlayingLabel";

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            //... other stuff

            intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The Fragment.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // other stuff

            bManger = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION);
            bManger.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    }

        private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {

                String[] topText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topText_array);
                songNowPlayingLabel.setText("Now Playing : " + topText[musicService.songPosn]);
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager bManger;
```

The problem is not to do with sending or receiving broadcasts, the problem is that the `TextView` is not updated even after the broadcast is received in the Fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic BroadcastReceivers: LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver vs registerReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715044/dynamic-broadcastreceivers-localbroadcastmanager-registerreceiver-vs-registerre)

Comment: Followed that, but the `TextView` is still not updated when the `onCompletionListener` is called or the notification skip to previous/next buttons are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of digging around here's what I came up with

In the MusicService.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        songPosn = 0  // defined as a public integer
        //other stuff
        topText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topText_array);
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }
```

Then I went into my playSong() method. This is the method that is called everytime the user does something with the audio so I figured it would lead to resolution of my problem.

```
    public void playSong() {
        //other stuff    
        intent.putExtra("nowPlaying", topText[songPosn]);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Then in my fragment.java file

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //other stuff
         broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    updateUI(intent);
                }
            };
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent){
        String nowPlaying = intent.getStringExtra("nowPlaying");
        songNowPlayingLabel.setText("Now Playing : " + nowPlaying);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using LocalBroadcastManager in the fragment.

Use below in MusicService.java:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

instead

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I'm able to send and receive the broadcast however the text for the `TextView` is not being updated

Comment: Use this : 
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        tv.setText("test");//Set the Text
            }
});`

Comment: It is already running on the UI thread. Even trying to call `runOnUiThread` is not possible